# Inno Setup Timer duration

Tags: timer, inno-setup

i just created a rotation banner that show some images during download process.

I used example found here

```pascal
function WrapTimerProc(Callback: TTimerProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
  external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall';    
function SetTimer(hWnd: HWND; nIDEvent, uElapse: UINT; lpTimerFunc: UINT): UINT;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: UINT): BOOL; 
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure OnSlideTimer(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; SysTime: DWORD);
begin
  case SlideID of 
    0: SlideID := 1;
    1: SlideID := 2;
    2: SlideID := 3;
    3: SlideID := 4;
    4: SlideID := 5;
    5: SlideID := 0;
  end;
  BackImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + IntToStr(SlideID + 1))+ ExpandConstant('{cm:imgbase}.bmp'));
end;

procedure StartSlideTimer;
var
  TimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
  TimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@OnSlideTimer, 4);

  TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 7000, TimerCallback);
end;
```

I set timer to fire after 7 seconds... but i see that the time betwen 2 change are allways different from 7 seconds and also are different all changes. (like 7 sec, 3 sec, 6 sec, ... different)

What is wrong?

Comment: That's because the `WM_TIMER` messages (which are processed by the `TimerProc` callback function) have lower priority in the message queue and that the Windows timer is not accurate. But I don't want to believe that there is so huge difference in time (that a timer with 7 seconds interval would generate e.g. a 3 second tick).

Comment: You can make it more precise if you'll generate frequent ticks (let's say 100 ms) and measure the duration from the last tick to the current tick (obtained by the `GetTickCount` function) and if that value will be greater than 7000, 7 seconds interval elapsed. Except that you can preload the bitmaps that you are showing.